# Convert Date without "T" and "Z" to Date with T-Z Format

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, iso8601

I have a JSON file with date format in the form of
`2021-09-21 15:37:29.590 +03:00`.

How can we convert it to a Date in a T-Z Format ?

Comment: Do you mean "ISO8601" with "T-Z format"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it into the `Date` constructor and call `toISOString`.

```js
const convert = (dateString) => new Date(dateString).toISOString();

console.log(convert('2021-09-21 15:37:29.590 +03:00')); // 2021-09-21T12:37:29.590Z
```

Comment: In Safari throws "RangeError: Invalid Date". See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)